# Difference between @cached_property and @lru_cache decorator

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django. Would be really helpful if someone can tell the difference between @cached_property and @lru_cache decorator in Django. 
Also when should I use which decorator in Django. Use cases would be really helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: FYI: for even better caching control over models and their fields, look at django-cacheops: https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops/blob/master/README.rst

Comment: look out for @ cached_property, confusingly it is _not_ actually a cached version of @ property as the name implies https://bugs.python.org/issue41523

Comment: This FAQ entry discusses the difference:  https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-cache-method-calls

Answer (score 32):

First and foremost, `lru_cache` is a decorator provided by the Python language itself as of version 3.4; `cached_property` is a decorator provided by Django for many years, while only being added to the Python language in version 3.8 in October 2019. That being said, they are similar.

`lru_cache` is specifically useful in functional programming. What it does is saves the results of function calls with a certain set of parameters. When a function decorated with `lru_cache` is called multiple times with the same parameters, the decorator will just return a cached result of the function result. This employs a method of programming called [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), and more specifically, [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). Using these methods, you can drastically speed up code which repeatedly calls functions that are computationally expensive.

Python also provides another similar decorator called `lfu_cache`. Both of these decorators accomplish memoization, however with different [replacement policies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_replacement_algorithm). `lru_cache` (least recently used) will fill it's cache and have to kick something out during the next decorated function call. This replacement policy dictates that the least recently used entry gets replaced by the new data. `lfu_cache` (least frequently used) dictates that replacements happen based on which entries are used the least.

`cached_property` *is* similar to `lru_cache` in the sense that it caches the result of expensive function calls. The only difference here is that it can only be used on *methods*, meaning the functions belong to an object. Furthermore, they can only be used on methods that have no other parameters aside from `self`. You would specifically want to use this during django development for a method on a class that hits the database. The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property) mention its usage on a model class which has a property method `friends`. This method presumably hits the database to gather a set of people who are friends of that instance of `Person`. Because calls to the database are expensive, we'd want to cache that result for later use.

Comment: [`cached_property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=cached_property#functools.cached_property) is included in the standard library as of python 3.8

Answer (score 12):

1. A major difference is that `lru_cache` will keep alive the objects in the cache, which might lead to memory leak, especially if the instance in which the lru_cache is applied is big (see: https://bugs.python.org/issue19859)

```py
class A:

  @property
  @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
  def x(self):
    return 123

for _ in range(100):
  A().x  # Call lru_cache on 100 different `A` instances

# The instances of `A()` are never garbage-collected:
assert A.x.fget.cache_info().currsize == 100
```

With `cached_property`, there is no cache, so no memory leak.

```py
class B:

  @functools.cached_property
  def x(self):
    return 123

b = B()
print(vars(b))  # {}
b.x
print(vars(b))  # {'x': 123}
del b  # b is garbage-collected
```

2. Another difference is that `@property` are read-only while `@cached_property` are not.  `cache_property` allows writes to the attributes [Refer Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property)

```
A().x = 123
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

```
B().x = 123  # Works
```

This is due to the fact that `@cached_property` are replacing the attribute, so the second call to `b.x` bypass the `B.x.get` descriptor call.

3. Another difference which likely don't matter in most cases is that `cached_property` is more performant if you access the same attribute multiple times, while `lru_cache` has overhead for the function call and attribute lookup. Note the difference is only visible with huge numbers.

```py
[A().x for _ in range(10_000)]
[B().x for _ in range(10_000)]

a = A()
b = B()

print(timeit.timeit(lambda: a.x, number=1_000_000))  # ~0.83
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: b.x, number=1_000_000))  # ~0.57
```

Comment: thanks for mentioning that @ cached_property attributes are not read only, this is an important detail which is strangely not called out in [the python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property). a bit misleading if you ask me...

Comment: @lunguini python docs clearly mentions that `cached_propery` allow writes to attributes.
Excerpt from [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property)  
The mechanics of cached_property() are somewhat different from property(). A regular property blocks attribute writes unless a setter is defined. In contrast, a cached_property allows writes.

Comment: you are right, the docs now explicitly discuss this. [in 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property) (the first version to include the @cached_property) they did not

Answer (score 6):

They serve different purposes.

`lru_cache` saves the least recent uses - you should specify `maxsize` which distinguishes how many computations of your function you can save. Once you surpass this number, the 'oldest' result is discarded and the new one is saved.

`cached_property` just computes the result and saves it. It doesn't take arguments unlike `lru_cache` (you can think of it as a `lru_cache` on an object type with maxsize = 1 with no arguments).

Comment: Is it correct that `lru_cache` with maxsize 1 is an equivalent, drop-in replacement for `cached_property`, except that `cached_property` may be more efficient? How relevant is the difference?
Is `lru_cache` a suitable fallback for Python < 3.8 to emulate `cached_property`?

Comment: No, lru_cache with size of 1 is not the same as cached_property, because lru_cache is a decorator which returns a function and cached_property creates a property (it does not require '()' to be invoked). It is similar in terms that once computed it does not need to be computed again.

Comment: I see. Is it effectively the same if adding an additional `@property` on top of the `@lru_cache` ?

Comment: The docs for [`cached_property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property) actually suggest stacking property on lru_cache as an alternative, so should be fine?