# Difference between functool's cache and lru_cache

Tags: python, recursion, functional-programming

Recently I came across [`functools.cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache) and didn't know how it differs from [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache).

I found [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49436833/difference-between-cached-property-and-lru-cache-decorator) about the difference between [`functools.cached_property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property) and `lru_cache` but nothing specifically for `cache` and `lru_cache`.

Comment: Why is this tagged with functional-programming and recursion?

Comment: `cache` and `lru_cache` are used to memoize repeated calls to a function with the same exact arguments. These are techniques that are used in recursion and functional programming. memoizing a recursive function wouldn't make sense if it relied on a global state that resulted in different outputs for the same exact input. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: This *question* has nothing to do with recursion, or functional programming. Don't just tag anything that could possibly be related to what you are asking about. And not relying on mutable global state doesn't really make something *functional programming*. But I leave it up to you.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your point. I don't insist on my interpretation. I'll let the tags there for some time to see what other users think. Will edit according to some form of majority opinion based on their inputs. Thanks again @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Its a bit of a tough one. memoization is not a strictly functional technique (although it does require functions not rely on side effects, or at least that they are deterministic) but it IS something familiar to most functional style coders and probably not many OO & Structured python coders. So in theory its something a functional minded coder might look up. Though I suspect its tagged because its part of the functools library (which are designed for functional style coding)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[`functools.cache`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functools.html#functools.cache) was newly added in version 3.9.

The documentation states:

> Simple lightweight unbounded function cache. Sometimes called “memoize”.
>
> Returns the same as `lru_cache(maxsize=None)`, creating a thin wrapper around a dictionary lookup for the function arguments. Because it never needs to evict old values, this is smaller and faster than `lru_cache()` with a size limit.

Example from the docs:

```py
@cache
def factorial(n):
    return n * factorial(n-1) if n else 1

>>> factorial(10)      # no previously cached result, makes 11 recursive calls
3628800
>>> factorial(5)       # just looks up cached value result
120
>>> factorial(12)      # makes two new recursive calls, the other 10 are cached
479001600
```

So, in short: `cache` and `lru_cache(maxsize=None)` are exactly the same ([link](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/functools.py#L646) to cpython source). But in cases where you don't want to limit the cache size, using `cache` may make the code clearer, since a least recently used cache without limit doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The last paragraph "[it] makes the code cleaner", is the crux. The doc is not wrong but a bit misleading.

Comment: Sorry for the late bump, I recently used functools - pressed ctrl+b (in Pycharm, to go into the module's code) and saw the the function `cache` is literally: `return lru_cache(maxsize=None)(user_function)` - So the code itself is pointless?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's pointless. It's just a wrapper around `lru_cache(maxsize=None)` for convenience. Considering that this is how it is used in many cases, it makes the code more readable for endusers.

Comment: I don't feel this answers the question. OP never specifies that it is `lru_cache(maxsize=None)`, but simply `lru_cache`. Calling it with a specific argument was not the question. What about _any other_ value of `maxsize`? How does _that_ compare to `cache`? Granted, maybe that can be researched apart for Python specifically, but this still doesn't answer the question, IMHO.